# Create a sound from scratch in DirectSound

Tags: playback, audio, directsound

Is there a way to create a sound from scratch using DirectSound, e.g play the notes a c, d, e, f,g etc? However, the sound must be realistic, and sound at least a little like a proper sound.

Thanks. I have tried to be as concise yet as detailed as I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what an [audio synthesizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_synthesis) does.  There are many techniques - you probably need to narrow down what you want to do before you can get useful advice.

However, the simplest technique that will produce a tone is to write an even number of periods of a sine wave of the [correct frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_key_frequencies) into a buffer, and [play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms811499.aspx) that as a [looping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms811499.aspx) buffer in DirectSound